# Is it possible to bring a bicycle on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bicycles

I have often wanted to bring my own bicycle while traveling. Are there some international regulations regarding bringing my bicycle on a plane? What should I expect to pay?

Comment: I don't see why airlines wouldn't allow you to check-in a folding bike, if packed properly. It might be worth looking up what the airline's policy on sports equipment is, and whether they consider bikes to fall under that category.

Comment: I work in a backpacker hostel in Australia and a couple of times a year we have a guest with a bicycle with the pedals removed in a big cardboard box with lots and lots and lots of packing tape. So this seems to be the normal way. I'm sure I've seen the boxes are the original box the bike was shipped in or in some way designed to contain a bike.

Comment: It'd be worth checking [bicycles stackexchange](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) for this as well. A quick check returned at least one [helpful looking answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/traveling-overseas-with-bikes)

Comment: Also see [Flying with your bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10664/flying-with-your-bike) on the same site.

Comment: Next question, can you leave your destination airport by bike? (avoiding roads that don't permit them). It would be reasonably awesome to collect the bike, drag it through customs, then just unpack and go.

Comment: @SteveJessop [You can at Heathrow](http://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/cycling).

Comment: It used to be common that you could transport a bicycle as extra luggage free of cost, as long as it was packed in the flat card board box they are transported in from the factory, with the tubes deflated, handlebars turned 90 degrees and pedals taken off. Most commonly people would pack needed tools (and pedals) with the bike and on arrival would ride away from the airport. These days charges are common and can be huge.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, it's possible!

Long answer: You will have to inform yourself with the airline you're flying with if they allow bikes on the plane, how much it costs, and how big the box you put it in can maximum be. Also it might be interesting to know if they allow cardboard boxes (otherwise you will have to get yourself a hard-case box to put your bicycle in (which can be expensive!)).

A lot of good information can be found here:

> [Airline Baggage Regulation for Bikes](http://www.ibike.org/encouragement/travel/bagregs.htm) (I'm not sure how up-to-date this one actually is, but it contains a list of a lot airlines and their regulations with respect to bicycles as luggage!)
>
> [How to Ship a Bicycle by Plane](http://www.ehow.com/how_4463861_ship-bicycle-plane.html)
>
> [How to Take Your Mountain Bike on an Airplane](http://www.ehow.com/how_14579_mountain-bike-airplane.html)

Comment: I have a friend who takes her folding bike on a cruise ship (and also on a plane), in a checked baggage. So yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 8):

Each airline has it's own rules. My friend carried his bike on 2 trips. Once it was free and the other time he had to pay some reasonable amount extra. He had to pack it/reassemble as compact as possible (turn and secure the wheel, flip pedals inward, etc.). He then packaged it in plastic tape (or whatever this thing people often wrap their luggage in is called) and dropped it at the oversize baggage counter.